# Matplotlib fill_between() does not save correctly as pdf with hatch

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter

I am running into the following issue when trying to save a matplotlib `fill_between()` plot as a pdf in ipython.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
A =[1,2,3,4,5,6]
B = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
plt.fill_between(A,A,B,color="none", hatch="\\\\\\\\\\\\", edgecolor="grey", linewidth=0.0,alpha=1)
plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```

when I run this, I find the following plot in the ipython notebook:
[image: image shown in the ipython notebook, or when saved directly as .png]

However, when I open the saved file, it instead looks like this:
[image: image when saved as a pdf]

The hatches are barely visible.  I need a high-quality plot, which is why I am trying to save as a pdf instead of as a png, for example.  Is there a way to increase the `linewidth` of the hatches when saving the pdf?

Comment: This seems to be a long standing problem, see: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/235 and https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/6198