# Hatches filling an empty color contour not saved in pdf python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]Hi,

I am trying to create a contour plot with the contours filled with hatches and no color. The following example works if I save it to .png but when I save it to .pdf the output is just the axis.

A code showing what I mean:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



delta = 0.025

x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.01, delta)


X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = plt.mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = plt.mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
Z = 10 * (Z1 - Z2)


levels=[0,1]
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z/X, 
                  levels,
                  #alpha=0.5,
                  colors='none', label='CHECK',
                   hatches=['\\'])

plt.tight_layout()   

plt.savefig('CHECK.pdf')
plt.show()
```

I checked [Matplotlib fill_between() does not save correctly as pdf with hatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333763/matplotlib-fill-between-does-not-save-correctly-as-pdf-with-hatch) and the links within, but no luck fixing the problem!

Comment: This works fine for me using matplotlib 2.0 and any of "Agg", "TkAgg" or "Qt4Agg" as backends. So you may try to use a different backend, `import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")` first.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot! I tried all of those backends and no luck :( Maybe it was not clear, but my problem is when saving it to pdf, not when saving it to .png Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I understand that you mean pdf, it's sufficiently clear from the question, no worries. I also tried it with matplotlib 1.5, which is also working. Are you sure that this is not a problem of your pdf viewer? (in the sense that hatches are there in the file, but the viewer does not show them) Can you try a different one?

Comment: Hi, sorry did not mean to sound patronizing it is just that I thought that TkAgg was used for png files.
I tried with 3 different viewers and no luck. Funny enough, if I save it to eps and then convert eps-to-pdf, I see the hatches for the pdf